# How to record screen while installing Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-installation, screen-capture

Besides recording the screen with an actual camera what are the options to make, for example, a Windows installation video tutorial?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An option is to use a second PC that has a video capture card installed. There are a few out there if you search that will let you input and record from computer sources like DVI or VGA.

You take your first pc video out connect that to a video splitter so you can run that video to a monitor and also the video capture card on the second pc.

Comment: Quality-wise, this is not only the best option for this situation, but for any screen recording needs. This method will not effect performance of the primary machine, and will allow for full resolution lossless capture. However this is also the most expensive way to do it.

Answer (score 62):

You can install Windows in a VM and record it with a screencapture-tool. (For example use [Virtual Box](http://virtualbox.org) to install windows)

> VirtualBox is a general-purpose full virtualizer for x86 hardware,
>   targeted at server, desktop and embedded use.

[image]

[Virtualbox Website](https://www.virtualbox.org)

Comment: this is by far the best option. other options include connecting your pc to the tv and record with some sort of device plugged in to the tv (meh, it sucks. just use the VM)

Comment: for the actual recording : use [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) and record the vm screen. It then allows you to simply delete unwanted frames, create/modify the mouse mouvements, add notes on the screen, set-up the pace of the whole thing, etc. A nifty free program to do tutorials. And it exports to several lightweight formats (swf, etc)

Comment: If you have VMWare Workstation available you can capture videos directly over your VM (see http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_capture.html)

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn Also not everyone has a capture card. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it inside the screen. But you have two ways:

1. Use the camera (Not recommended)
2. Use a Virutal Machine

I recommend the second way. You can use a virtual software like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/%E2%80%8E) (Freeware) or [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com).
You can make a virtual operation system and install your windows inside it. During the installation, you can record the screen.
The virtual machine will run in your OS into a SandBox, so it won't touch your OS files until you want.

Comment: VMWare Player or VMWare Server is free

Comment: VirutalBox is fully free. i recommend it

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc VMware Server was discontinued *years* ago.

Comment: @MDMarra: really. I haven't used VMWare for a long time. Thanks for the information

Comment: VM Player is not free for commercial use, but Virtual Box isn't free for commercial. That is a PUEL .... (Personal Use and Evaluation License). That's why i recommended VM player. despite that the VM player have a "Non-commercial use only" heading, it is slightly better than virtual box in compatibility, probably because of the abundance and success of ESX server. Guess no one interest to an Oracle Virtual Box server.

Answer (score 0):

Only personal choice, I would use VM Player + CamStudio, which give me best experience on produce some installation video.

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0|PLAYER-600-A|product_downloads

http://camstudio.org